# Samba timezone is UTC while Ubuntu America/Los_Angeles

Tags: 18.04, samba4

Ubuntu 18.04 with Samba Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu. Ubuntu is set to correct timezone, & time synchronizes & displays as expected. But the Samba log files are timestamped with UTC while Ubuntu is Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800).

How do I set the timezone for Samba so that the log files are correct?

Comment: This would seem to be the responsibility of your Samba configuration.